# Cypress: I need to exit the for loop if the condition is satisfied

Tags: cypress

Below is the code which I am using.

I am working with **Cypress + Cucumber + Typescript**.

**Scenario**: I need to get a list of unique values using a for loop. Then I am passing this value to an API to verify some condition and if the condition is met I want to exit the loop.

To exit the loop I somewhere read a solution that if I use "return false" as first-line in if condition then loop will exit which seems to work fine.

The issue here is, when I try to set a flag from inside the for-if loop to the instance variable then the value read by if condition (for exiting the loop) is not picking the updated value of instance variable. And the loop continues to run.

Below is the code snippet:

```js
class test {
  static isVinavailable: boolean = false;
  static setEligibleVehicleVinTest() {
    cy.xpath(eligibleForSaleVehicleVin).then((esv) => {
      const listingCount = Cypress.$(esv).length;
      for (let i = 0; i < listingCount; i++) {
        let text123 = esv.eq(i).text();
        genericAction.getAuthenticationKey();
        cy.fixture("authResp.json")
          .then((authResp) => {
            cy.request({
              method: "GET",
              url: vehicleCheckEligibility + text123,
              headers: {
                Authorization: authResp.access_token,
              },
            });
          })
          .then((response: any) => {
            cy.wait(5000);
            let responseDataelig = response.body;
            if (
              (responseDataelig.val1 =
                "Y" &&
                responseDataelig.val2 === "N" &&
                responseDataelig.val3 === "N")
            ) {
              this.isVinavailable = true;
            }
          });
        if (this.isVinavailable) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class test {
  static isVinavailable = false;
  static setEligibleVehicleVinTest(): Cypress.Chainable<boolean> {
    return cy.xpath(eligibleForSaleVehicleVin).each(($el) => {
      let text123 = $el.text();
      cy.fixture('authResp.json')
        .then((authResp) => {
          return cy.request({
            // your code block
          });
        })
        .then((response: any) => {
          // your code block
          if (condition) {
            this.isVinavailable = true;
            return false;
          };
        });
    }).then(() => {
      return this.isVinavailable;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: @celoagae Thanks for the response. The issue I am facing here is that I am hitting an API and then adding IF condition to the response. Due to this multiple then() is used in my code which is causing problem is exit f for loop. I believe I am doing wrong in chaining the code. I have changed the code as per the suggestion. Requesting you to please help me with chainig the code so that the solution u gave works fine. Thanks in advance     
`````````

Comment: Then I advise that:  1) you better use `.each()` because return false will break `.each()` loop. 2) by using `.each()`, you no need to define a `flag`. you can directly break the loop within `.each()`. see here please, here is the same as your problem: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/5485#issuecomment-547021325

Comment: Ur suggested code works perfectly fine but my use case is different  like the IF condition in my code is inside then which doesn't exit the loop when i add return false. 
need your help in writing this code so that it works fine and exit the loop when condition is met

Comment: sample code:
`````` static sampleTest() {
    let flagToReturn = false;
      cy.xpath(eligibleForSaleVehicleVin).each(($esv, index, $list)=> {
        cy.fixture("authResp.json")
        .then((authResp) => {
            //--Some code here---
        })
      }).then((response: any) => {
        let responseDataelig = response.body;
        if (responseDataelig.val1=== "Y" &&
       responseDataelig.val2=== "N" &&
       responseDataelig.val3=== "N"
     ) {
      flagToReturn=true;
      return false;
     }
 })
    }
```````

Comment: your sample code in the comment is different from your actual question. in your sample code, once your .each() loop is completed,  then you are setting your flag to true (or whatever). Thus, you can not break the loop as per your sample code, so you can not achieve what you want. But in your first code example in the original question: you miss to return a response: try my edited answer with `return` and `.each()` above. hope it will work.

Comment: Thank you so much for ur time and response. This suggested code doesn't work for me and the logic of code is same in all the comments I asked.